# Context API, how to not use a class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to make and get props in all components with the funcional component and hooks?

at example iam making a js file with class with functions inside like getBooks(), getNotes(), then i making a context file and importing this in index.js and use a class for provider value, like below.

```js
import {BookStoreContext} from "./components/bookstore-service-context";
import {BookStoreService} from "./services";

const bookStoreService = new BookStoreService();

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ErrorBoundry>
            <BookStoreContext.Provider value={BookStoreService}>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <App/>
    </BrowserRouter>
            </BookStoreContext.Provider>
        </ErrorBoundry>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Have provided a step by step guide about how to use Context with the Hooks. Hope this will help you and many other developers as well. Do vote and accept the answer if this is helpful to you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once our `Context` is ready ( *A global data to be used in the project)*.We can use `useContext()` Hook to consume our context in React-Hooks. This way we avoid class Based `ContextName.Consumer` Component in our Application.

The will provide step by step guide about how to work with Context API in Hooks with the example below.

**1. First we create our Context File (Which will have our Global Data)**

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";

const books = [
  { id: 1, name: "The way of the kings" },
  { id: 2, name: "The people of Paradise" },
  { id: 3, name: "Protest of the Farmers" }
];
// First we need to create our context
const BookContext = createContext();

// createContext returns 2 things. Provider and Consumer. We will only need Provider

const BookContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState(books);

  const removeBook = (id) => {
    setBooks(books.filter((book) => book.id !== id));
  };

  return (
    <BookContext.Provider value={{ books, removeBook }}>
      {children}
    </BookContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default BookContextProvider;
```

We used `createContext()` method to create our Context. This returns (as before Hooks also) 2 things. `Consumer` and `Provider`. Since we will work with Hooks we only need `Provider` and in place of `Consumer`, we'll use `useContext()` in our components to consume this context.

**2. Our Context is ready now.** (**Note:**`BookContext`  is our `Context` and `BookContextProvider` is simply a component in which we have our Context data). We will need to wrap our entire `App` around`BookContextProvder` Component so that all the Child Components used in the Application will have access to the Global Context.

```
    import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import "./styles.css";

    import BookContextProvider from "./BookContext";

    export default function App() {
     return (
       <div className="App">
        <BookContextProvider>
          <BookList/>
        </BookContextProvider>
      </div>
     );
    }
```

If you notice, I have Used `BookList` Component within `BookContextProvider`, that is to do with the setup we did in our `Context` file, where we used `{children}`. So, `BookList` Component is passed as `children` prop to the `BookContextProvider` Component in our `BookContext.js` file. (This may take some time for newbies  to grasp the concept).

**3. Once All the setup is ready we can consume context in our Child Components**:

So in my `BookList` Component, I want to access `books`  and also have the access to the `removeBook` handler. `*We make use of useContext() Hook to do that.*`

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { BookContext } from "./BookContext";

const BookList = () => {
  const { books, removeBook } = useContext(BookContext);

  console.log(books); // We have our Books available now
  console.log(removeBook); // We have our removeBook Handler as well
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>BookList Component</h1>
      {books.length > 0 &&
        books.map((book) => {
          return <div key={book.id}>{book.name}</div>;
        })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default BookList;
```

> In the above `BookList` Component we are now consuming our Context
> using `useContext()` Hook.

**COMPLETE CODESANDBOX DEMO:** https://codesandbox.io/s/react-context-and-hooks-vcsfn?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Do Accept the answer and vote on my answer. I believe this will help lot of other young developers in future :)

Answer (score 1):

See [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext).

Just do

```js
// functional component
const someComponent = () => {
  const BookStoreService = useContext(BookStoreContext);

  // calling a method in the BookStoreService class
  BookStoreService.getBooks();

  return <></>
}
```

Note that if your methods like `getBooks()` are asynchronous (i.e. fetch data from a server), it's probably best to call them within a side effect hook like [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Comment: thank you, so its impossible to give up a Class in this situation to get functions ?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're pointing out here. It'll be a lot more helpful if you could show what you intend to write `BookStoreService` as, using "functions".